# MySite navigates to person.aspx page rather than actual mysite

Tags: 2013

I have MySites set up to use a personal site location `http://company.com/personal/`, but when I try to navigate to my personal site, I get this URL instead: `http://company.com/Person.aspx?accountname=DOMAIN\username`

I have a wildcard inclusion for `personal` set up on the web app which hosts the MySite Host Site Collection.

What's going on here? It seems as though there isn't a site collection being created for a user's profile.

Comment: Are you sure it is always at person.aspx, even if you click for example "My Files" (or what it's called, don't have SP up right now) or "Blog"? Lot of the other link alternative should actually point to the person.aspx

Comment: @RobertLindgren I only have "About me" and "People" on the side bar :\

Comment: Make sure Self Service Site Creation is correctly configured on your mysite web application, seems it can't create the personal site collections!

Comment: @RobertLindgren That's the thing though, self service site creation is enabled and when I look at "View All Site Collections" on the web app, I can see a whole ton of profiles with their own site collection. Some don't though... also some profiles have 0 entered for "Personal Site Capabilities" and some have no entry at all. Maybe the two are related?

Comment: Could be! It think you need to find that error you get when trying to update the 0 from the ULS logs :/ good luck!

Comment: the link you mentioned is typically profile page not my site. is this behaviour for all users or only with couple. Try to access your own mysite.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem before and solved it doing this.

Go to Sharepoint Central Administration -> Application Management -> Manage service applications-> User profile Service App -> Setup my site

Edit My Site Host and Personal Site Location and input the right location.

Answer (score 1):

As @WaqasSarwarMCSE mentioned, "the link you mentioned is typically profile page not my site.".

Try to navigate to `http://company.com/personal/username` or `http://company.com/personal/DOMAIN\username`. It should redirect you to `default.aspx`. Also if you navigate to *Site Contents* from your `http://company.com/personal/` you should end up to your own site collection, ie. under `/personal/`.

For what comes to your missing links from Quick Launch (Blog, Tasks, ..): They are probably not available due to *Personal Site Capabilities* value 0. I had a similar issue and for me the easiest way to fix it was to set up the My Sites site collection up again from scratch. For me the sites were set up illogically.

Comment: Actually, when I try to navigate to a personal site like `http://company.com/personal/username`, it redirects me to the Person.aspx page

Comment: Did you try to navigate to the mentioned URL with `default.aspx` in the end? You could also try to navigate to `http://company.com/personal/username/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx` which is the `Site Contents` page. If you can't reach them, I'd expect there to be problem on the creation of personal sites.

Answer (score 1):

We also ran into this problem but our solution was different. We had recently imported My Site databases into a new farm and the Users Profile GUID did not match the Web Property so they were being redirected to person.aspx. We solved it by running something like this.

```
$Web = Get-SPWeb http://[MySiteURL]/personal/[UserID]
$Web.SetProperty("urn:schemas-microsoft-com:sharepoint:portal:profile:userprofile_guid", "[NewGUID]")
$Web.Update()
```

You can get the **NewGUID** by querying `UserProfileManager` in PowerShell or by going to

**User Profile Service Application -> Manage User Profiles -> Find the user profile that is having issues -> Edit User Profile**

Then get the **GUID** out of the URL `ProfAdminEdit.aspx?guid=[NewGUID]`